# "The request failed with an empty response" from asmx web service

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, soap, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We have an ".asmx" web service which is referred into a VSTO add-in project. After installing the add-in  Some clients getting error as "The request failed with an empty response". Its is working fine as expected for some other clients. What could be the reason?

Note :

1. We added the web service as Web Reference
2. For some clients its working as Expected
3. We hosted the service as Azure App service.

Code Sample:

```
 try { 
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        APMService svc = new APMService();
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 40;
        LoginResponseStatus lresponse = svc.LoginUser("UserName", "Password", "LicenceKey");
        txtBox.Text = lresponse.status.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtBox.Text = ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace + "\n" + ex.InnerException;
        }
```

Error Response:

```
    System.Net.WebException: The request failed with an empty response.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Service.MethodName(String loggedInUserEmail)
   at ServiceCallerLocatin.MethodName(String LoggedInUserEmail)
Stack trace:
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

Comment: When you debugged the web service (the server-side part), what was it returning?

Comment: It will return object with some details specific to that user if the authentication success other wise it will returns the corresponding error code to that object

Comment: If it works for some and not others then it's very difficult to say what the problem could be, because it could be so many things.  Do you have any debug logging in the web service?  If not I suggest adding some (Serilog is easy to retro-fit)

Comment: We have added logs in our server side code but in the failed case none of the logs are happening. Actually the method its self starting with a log.

Comment: If the first thing the method does is log but you see no log entries, then it's not being called.  It may be something as simple as an incorrect parameter type being used, so the call isn't made.  You need to know what data causes the failure so you can reproduce it.  When you can do that then you can try and follow the logic that causes the failure.

Comment: Is there any Environmental settings cause this problem like firewall  ,antivirus or any other network related things? Since the same code is working for others and all the input are strings only.  if the input are not valid means it should show error message

Comment: We are not able to reproduce this issue in any our native system and its happening only in our client system. So how we can trouble shoot this problem effectively.